# Fastest Search algorithm in Nested hierarchy of array list in java

Tags: java, algorithm, search, arraylist

I have a situation where i have list of  Users listed according according to their departments and sub departments.

I have created data structure where i have arraylist of departments where each item contains arraylist of sub departments where each sub department further has array list of users.

I know that we can iterate through each list and search if it contains the user
can any one suggest the the fastest way to search through that heirarcal list.

```
-abc
 |__sec1
    |__pras
    |__muk

 |__sec2
    |__pras
    |__muk

 |__sec3
    |__pras
    |__muk

-pqr
 |__sec1
    |__pras
    |__muk

 |__sec2
    |__pras
    |__muk

 |__sec3
    |__pras
    |__muk
```

Above is my hierarchical model which might grow above 1 lacs users.

```
ArrayList<Model_Departments> list_departments=new ArrayList<>();
String[] TESTING={"Mansur","Bhoopathi","Somya"};
String[] NPD={"Aravindan","Vijaya","Mohit Mathur","Mukesh Garg","Prateek shrivastva","Kishore Bhatt","Sagar Gupta","Vishal"};
String[] PS1={"Bhanu","Mukesh Kumar","Kundan"};
String[] HR={"Pratusha","Shatabadi","Naveen"};
String[] NETWORK={"Devakaran","JJ","N. Prasad"};
ArrayList<Model_Users> list_users=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Model_Sub_Department> lis_sub_deptt=new ArrayList<>();
Model_Users model_user;
Model_Departments model_deptt;
Model_Sub_Department model_sub_department;



model_user=new Model_Users("Aravindan","NPD Soul",true);
    list_users.add(model_user);
    model_user=new Model_Users("Vijaya","NPD Karta Dharta",true);
    list_users.add(model_user);
    model_user=new Model_Users("Mohit Mathur","Majnu",true);
    list_users.add(model_user);
    model_user=new Model_Users("Kishore Dhutt","Always Admin",true);
    list_users.add(model_user);
    model_user=new Model_Users("Sagar Gupta","Android cheeee",true);
    list_users.add(model_user);
    model_user=new Model_Users("Vishal","Link Baba",true);
    list_users.add(model_user);
    model_user=new Model_Users("Mukesh Garg","I am loving it",true);
    list_users.add(model_user);
    model_user=new Model_Users("Prateek","Masti with @friends",true);
    list_users.add(model_user);
    model_sub_department=new Model_Sub_Department("NPD",list_users);
    lis_sub_deptt.add(model_sub_department);
    model_sub_department=new Model_Sub_Department("Ps1",list_users);
    lis_sub_deptt.add(model_sub_department);

    model_deptt=new Model_Departments("Engineering",lis_sub_deptt);
    list_departments.add(model_deptt);
    model_deptt=new Model_Departments("Testing",lis_sub_deptt);
    list_departments.add(model_deptt);
    model_deptt=new Model_Departments("Human Resources",lis_sub_deptt);
    list_departments.add(model_deptt);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why not store a map where key is indeification of the user and value is the user's object?

Comment: Please describe your current solution in detail: Example of the structure (in code) and how you search them. How many users / departments are we dealing with?

Comment: If they are nested lists with no other constraints (or allowances) then a loop is the 'best' method.. it probably is fast enough.

Comment: You might want to (translate lacs and) avoid using `class`es in declaring variables or, worse, parameter: use the most abstract `interface` specifying the operations wanted. (Heed amit's advice: it is perfectly OK for a user to be in a `Map` and the `List` of a (sub-)department (or several) at once.) (The class name `Model_Users` carries a plural-s -?)

Comment: @amit  what if several users have same name and inthat case the key will be suplicated